# SUM a field with distinct grouped records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a really tricky SQL issue which I can't get to the bottom of. I have a SQL view which lists servers and their power connections to power strips (around 44,500 connections to around 8,000 power strips. What I now need to do is create a view which shows a single entry for each power strip and its total load in watts.

This is a short example of the table that I'm working from:

```
POWERSTRIP_VOB_ID                       DEVICE_VOB_ID                           WATTS
5FA38587-FA3E-4BF0-B87C-B782B0FD9284    988BD4A4-CAC7-4CC9-B1F8-274D75C48796    17
5FA38587-FA3E-4BF0-B87C-B782B0FD9284    67174BE5-9065-4131-8817-EB584F940A39    17
5FA38587-FA3E-4BF0-B87C-B782B0FD9284    44713911-F1D8-45E6-9FFA-DCD29F0A5EDA    1164
5FA38587-FA3E-4BF0-B87C-B782B0FD9284    D4495808-AE45-4F8E-ADB0-A97C5F79FD70    17
5FA38587-FA3E-4BF0-B87C-B782B0FD9284    A9B17915-85F2-4FE1-915A-044312177845    7481
5FA38587-FA3E-4BF0-B87C-B782B0FD9284    5AC7AA8A-8A56-4E09-A607-98985782B32B    1746
5FA38587-FA3E-4BF0-B87C-B782B0FD9284    A9B17915-85F2-4FE1-915A-044312177845    7481
5FA38587-FA3E-4BF0-B87C-B782B0FD9284    A9B17915-85F2-4FE1-915A-044312177845    7481
```

As you can see, all of the lines have the same `POWERSTRIP_VOB_ID`. In this example all of the servers have at least one connection to this powerstrip. You will also note that the Device starting with `A9B17915` has three connections to the power strip.

If I use `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` the `POWERSTRIP_VOB_ID` with a SUM on Watts I get a result of 25,404. What I need to do is essentially ignore any of the duplicate connections so that the query only sums the servers once for the powerstrip .

In this example I would be looking for the sum of:

```
POWERSTRIP_VOB_ID                       DEVICE_VOB_ID                           WATTS
5FA38587-FA3E-4BF0-B87C-B782B0FD9284    988BD4A4-CAC7-4CC9-B1F8-274D75C48796    17
5FA38587-FA3E-4BF0-B87C-B782B0FD9284    67174BE5-9065-4131-8817-EB584F940A39    17
5FA38587-FA3E-4BF0-B87C-B782B0FD9284    44713911-F1D8-45E6-9FFA-DCD29F0A5EDA    1164
5FA38587-FA3E-4BF0-B87C-B782B0FD9284    D4495808-AE45-4F8E-ADB0-A97C5F79FD70    17
5FA38587-FA3E-4BF0-B87C-B782B0FD9284    A9B17915-85F2-4FE1-915A-044312177845    7481
5FA38587-FA3E-4BF0-B87C-B782B0FD9284    5AC7AA8A-8A56-4E09-A607-98985782B32B    1746
```

This should result in 1 record in the view which would be something like:

```
POWERSTRIP_VOB_ID                       WATTS
5FA38587-FA3E-4BF0-B87C-B782B0FD9284    10442
```

Hopefully I've explained that well enough.

I've played with `GROUP BY`, `DISTINCT` and `SUM(DISTINCT)` and can't seem to get the output that I need.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Simon

Comment: why can just direct `group by POWERSTRIP_VOB_ID ` & `sum(watts)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
SELECT POWERSTRIP_VOB_ID, SUM(WATTS)
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT POWERSTRIP_VOB_ID, DEVICE_VOB_ID, WATTS
        FROM   myTable
)
GROUP BY POWERSTRIP_VOB_ID;
```

The inner query excludes the duplicates, and the outer query makes the sums.

From your description I get that it is impossible for 2 records to have the same POWERSTRIP_VOB_ID and DEVICE_VOB_ID values, but differing WATTS. I suppose that would be an indication of database inconsistency. Anyway, if this occurs, the above query will sum both values.

Comment: That is awesome!!! Need to do some more testing but it certainly works for the example. Thank you very much!! Simon

Comment: You may be interested in the points raised by my variation on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the answer already posted, you could also try this:

```
SELECT POWERSTRIP_VOB_ID, SUM(WATTS)
FROM (
    SELECT POWERSTRIP_VOB_ID, DEVICE_VOB_ID, WATTS
    FROM   myTable
    GROUP BY POWERSTRIP_VOB_ID, DEVICE_VOB_ID, WATTS
)
GROUP BY POWERSTRIP_VOB_ID;
```

This may look like a trivial variation on the SELECT DISTINCT answer, but it is not for a number of reasons:

1. Over large datasets there are numerous examples give on the web where GROUP BY performs significantly faster than SELECT DISTINCT. While we as programmers may see that the two produce the identical result set for this case, the semantics of the two operations are different, and there are cases where the output would actually be different - such as whenever there is a calculated column.

   - SELECT DISTINCT is defined to perform a SORT followed by elimination of duplicates. The storage requirement thus is for sufficient additional space to store the working result set, plus whatever is needed for the selected *sort* algorithm.
   - GROUP BY is defined to collects buckets, and thus the storage requirement is only for the number of buckets (ie unique values) that actually exist.

   The time requirement for both is n * Log(n). The performance difference is probably more noticeable when *tempdb* is not on an SSD.
2. All *REAL* SQL programmers know that any use of DISTINCT looks amateur (which may be fed by a, whether conscious or subconscious, appreciation of the above performance difference). Thus SQL programmers who care to NOT appear as amateur will always replace a SELECT DISTINCT with a GROUP BY as a matter of principle. My tongue is firmly in cheek here - but given point (1) above this is actually a valid reason to ***remember*** that almost all valid uses of SELECT DISTINCT can be replaced with a GROUP BY.
3. The most common case for use of SELECT DISTINCT is a missing JOIN clause causing artificial duplicates. This fact is not appreciated by amateur SQL programmers, who then eliminate the duplicates with a SELECT DISTINCT. One of the most common ways to tune SQL written by amateurs is to simply search for all uses of SELECT DISTINCT and add the missing JOIN clauses, or take advantage of (1) and replace with a GROUP BY if the elimination of duplicates is actually necessary. Non-amateur SQL programmers signal that this step has been performed by not ever using SELECT DISTINCT, thus saving any reviewer the effort of doing so.

Comment: You are absolutely right to note that there seems to be a problem with the "source" data that the OP has presented. There should not be such duplicates in the first place, and it shows bad design or bad `SQL` below the surface.